# how to convert unordered list to table?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to convert unordered list to table. below code returns unordered list.

```
var jsonString = '{"data":{"2G":[{"amount":"9","detail":"35 MB 2G Data , Post 35 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"1 Day","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"16","detail":"90 MB 2G Data, Post 90 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"2 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"28","detail":"160 MB 2G Data, Post 160 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"4 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"54","detail":"300 MB 2G Data, Post 300 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"7 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"78","detail":"310 MB 2G Data , Post 310 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"10 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"95","detail":"550 MB 2G Data, Post 550 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"14 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"125","detail":"700 MB 2G Data, Post 700 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"18 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"155","detail":"850 MB 2G Data, Post 850 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"21 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"179","detail":"1 GB 2G Data, Post 1 GB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"198","detail":"Hero Recharge : Get 1.25 GB 2G Data assured benefit (upto 3 GB 2G Data with hero recharge)","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"199","detail":"2 GB Unlimted 2G Data, Post 2 GB your speed will be reduced up to 40kbps","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"249","detail":"3 GB Unlimted 2G Data, Post 3 GB your speed will be reduced up to 40kbps","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"205","detail":"1 GB 2G Data Day + Extra 1 GB 2G Night Data (12AM to 6AM)","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"305","detail":"2 GB 2G Data Day + Extra 2 GB 2G Night Data (12AM to 6AM)","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"395","detail":"3 GB 2G Data Day + Extra 3 GB 2G Night Data (12AM to 6AM)","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"57","detail":"190 MB 2G Data, Post 190 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"98","detail":"300 MB 2G Data, Post 300 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"}]},"resCode":"200","resText":"SUCCESS"}';

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $amountlist = $('#amount');
    var $detaillist = $('#detail');
    var $validitylist = $('#validity');
    var $talktimelist = $('#talktime');
    var myData = $.parseJSON(jsonString);    
    console.log(myData.data["2G"]);
    $.each(myData.data["2G"], function(i,dataElem) {
        $('<li>' + dataElem.amount + '</li>').appendTo($amountlist);
        $('<li>' + dataElem.detail + '</li>').appendTo($detaillist);
        $('<li>' + dataElem.validity + '</li>').appendTo($validitylist);
        $('<li>' + dataElem.talktime + '</li>').appendTo($talktimelist);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NJMyD/5183/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NJMyD/5210/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Example with easy readability:-***

```js
var jsonString = '{"data":{"2G":[{"amount":"9","detail":"35 MB 2G Data , Post 35 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"1 Day","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"16","detail":"90 MB 2G Data, Post 90 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"2 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"28","detail":"160 MB 2G Data, Post 160 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"4 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"54","detail":"300 MB 2G Data, Post 300 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"7 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"78","detail":"310 MB 2G Data , Post 310 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"10 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"95","detail":"550 MB 2G Data, Post 550 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"14 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"125","detail":"700 MB 2G Data, Post 700 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"18 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"155","detail":"850 MB 2G Data, Post 850 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"21 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"179","detail":"1 GB 2G Data, Post 1 GB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"198","detail":"Hero Recharge : Get 1.25 GB 2G Data assured benefit (upto 3 GB 2G Data with hero recharge)","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"199","detail":"2 GB Unlimted 2G Data, Post 2 GB your speed will be reduced up to 40kbps","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"249","detail":"3 GB Unlimted 2G Data, Post 3 GB your speed will be reduced up to 40kbps","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"205","detail":"1 GB 2G Data Day + Extra 1 GB 2G Night Data (12AM to 6AM)","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"305","detail":"2 GB 2G Data Day + Extra 2 GB 2G Night Data (12AM to 6AM)","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"395","detail":"3 GB 2G Data Day + Extra 3 GB 2G Night Data (12AM to 6AM)","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"57","detail":"190 MB 2G Data, Post 190 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"},{"amount":"98","detail":"300 MB 2G Data, Post 300 MB you will be charged at 4p\/10kb","validity":"28 Days","talktime":"0"}]},"resCode":"200","resText":"SUCCESS"}';

$(document).ready(function() {
   var amountlist = $('#amountlist tbody');
    var myData = $.parseJSON(jsonString);    
    $.each(myData.data["2G"], function(i,dataElem) {
        $('<tr>').appendTo(amountlist);
        $('<td>' + dataElem.amount + '</td>').appendTo(amountlist);
        $('<td>' + dataElem.detail + '</td>').appendTo(amountlist);
        $('<td>' + dataElem.validity + '</td>').appendTo(amountlist);
        $('<td>' + dataElem.talktime + '</td>').appendTo(amountlist);
        $('</tr>').appendTo(amountlist);
    });
});
```

```css
table >tbody{
 word-break: keep-all;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id = "amountlist">
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>amount</th>
    <th>detail</th>
    <th>validity</th>
    <th>talktime</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

***Note:- change code+css according to your wish.Thanks***

Comment: thank for you answer. but problem with data is not appending to table. can you please help me with. i want to update above data to datatable

Comment: you need to check dta-tables with jquery example demo. It's very wast topic and can not support here.  Check here different example:- https://datatables.net/examples/index

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka   it's totally fine.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var rows = '<tr><th>amount</th><th>detail</th><th>validity</th><th>talktime</th></tr>';
  $.each(myData.data["2G"], function(i, dataElem) {
    rows += '<tr><td>' + dataElem.amount + '</td><td>' + dataElem.detail + '</td><td>' + dataElem.validity + '</td><td>' + dataElem.talktime + '</td></tr>';

  });

  $('#tab').html(rows);
});
```

In your HTML

```
<table id="tab"></table>
```